# What's the difference between property Entity Reference and property in Entity Data Model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have three tables structure like following

```
AppUser             User                App              
*********           ******              ******
AppUserId           UserId              AppId
UserId
AppId
```

UserId and AppId of Table AppUser is foreign keys to table User and App. When I generate **3 tables to Entity Data Model, it has three class AppUser, User as well as App**. However, I don't uderstand **AppUser.UserReference and AppUser.User**

Answer (score 3):

AppUser.User is navigational property of type User, AppUser.UserReference is of type 
`EntityReference<User>` . They are comletely different objects.

You can use AppUser.User to access related user properties or to change related user.
You can use AppUser.UserReference, for example, to load related user with `EntityReference<T>.Load()` method.

In fact AppUser.UserReference.Value equals AppUser.User.